# Image change onPress in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, mobile-development

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native'
import HeaderComponent from '../../components/HeaderComponent'
import NavigationFooter from '../../components/NavigationFooter'

const ReportScreen = () => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.viewcontainer}>
            <HeaderComponent title="Taak" />

            <Text style={styles.subtext}>Selecteer het taak type</Text>
```

I want to change the image `onPress` in the `TouchableOpacity` below, but I don't know how to do that with `useState`

```js
            <TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.graycontainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.grayimg} source={require('../../../assets/report/gray.png')} />
                        <Text style={styles.graytext}>Grijs</Text>)
                    </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            

        </View>        
    
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you it with Pressable like this:

```
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';

import imagesOn from '../../../assets/report/grayOn.png'
import imagesOff from '../../../assets/report/grayOFF.png'
let [flag, setflag] = React.useState(true);

let changeImage = () => setFlag(previousState => !previousState);

let imagePath= flag ? imagesOn : imagesOff
------
-----
<Pressable onPress={ () => changeImage() }>
            <View style={styles.graycontainer}>
                <Image style={styles.grayimg} source={imagePath} />
                <Text style={styles.graytext}>Grijs</Text>)
            </View>
    </Pressable>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to change back to first image on second press?

Comment: Edited the answer above, please check

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native'
import HeaderComponent from '../../components/HeaderComponent'
import NavigationFooter from '../../components/NavigationFooter'

const ReportScreen = () => {
  const img = require("../../../assets/report/gray.png")
  const [imageAsset, setImageAsset] = useState(img)

  const handleImageChange = () => {
    const newImg = require("../path/to/your/image")
    setImageAsset(newImg)
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewcontainer}>
      <HeaderComponent title="Taak" />

      <Text style={styles.subtext}>Selecteer het taak type</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleImageChange}>
        <View style={styles.graycontainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.grayimg}
            source={imageAsset}
          />
          <Text style={styles.graytext}>Grijs</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Save the initial image in useState as above and change the state in the onPress handler with the image you want, which is then passed to the TouchableOpacity. Make sure your styles are set properly on the Image component, especially width and height, else the image will not be displayed.

On a side note, TouchableOpacity might get deprecated in later versions of RN. Consider using Pressable instead.

Comment: Thnx for the advice it worked wonders. But is it also possible to revert on second press to the first image?

Comment: The other answer shows how. Its the best way. Please try it and mark it as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.